# Unable to create chrome webdriver in an abstract class

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

This code is working just fine:

```
class example:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        remote_debug_port=8956
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument(f'--remote-debugging-port={remote_debug_port}')
        options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", options=options)

a = example()
```

## create webdriver inside an Abstract class, then create an child class.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

from selenium import webdriver


class ChromeDriverBase(ABC):
    def __init__(self, url_source:str,
                webdriver_path:str="/usr/bin/chromedriver",
                wait_time:int=10,
                remote_port:int=2345) -> None:
        self.url_source = url_source
        self.wait_time = wait_time
        self.remote_port = remote_port
        self.create_options()
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(webdriver_path, options=self.options)
    
    def create_options(self):
        self.options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        self.options.add_argument(f'--remote-debugging-port={self.remote_port}')
        self.options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        self.options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        self.options.add_argument('--headless')
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-infobars')
        self.options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        
    
    @abstractmethod
    def function1(self):
        pass


class ChromeChild(ChromeDriverBase):
    def __init__(self, url_source: str, wait_time: int = 10, remote_port: int = 2345) -> None:
        super().__init__(url_source=url_source, wait_time=wait_time, remote_port=remote_port)


    def function1(self):
        # just for illustration
        return self.url_source


a = ChromeChild(url_source='www.google.com')

# this trigger this  error 
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not 
created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 109
Current browser version is 103.0.5060.114 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

I checked the version:

```
Google Chrome 109.0.5414.119 
ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74
```

Comment: Well, it's not getting the 109 version of Chrome.  It's getting 103.  Is this, perhaps, running on a different server?

Comment: @TimRoberts, I am running both code on the same machine. It make me crazy!! Did you run the first part ?

Comment: Your first example doesn't actually run the browser.  Did you do a request in that configuration?

Comment: @TimRoberts if you want to show the browser, just comment the option `--headless` and you will see it

Comment: And if YOU type `/usr/bin/google-chrome --version`, what do you see?

Comment: @TimRoberts, as I write in the question 109.***

Comment: What happens if you specify the path `/usr/bin/google-chrome`  to the driver? Maybe the driver found another chrome executable?

Comment: The evidence in the error does not support that assertion.  And your question did not show where those version numbers came from.  That's the issue.  You have multiple versions somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your output log states:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not 
created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 109
Current browser version is 103.0.5060.114 with binary path /usr/bin/google-chrome
```

First, please check your local chrome version from the path `/usr/bin/google-chrome` and not the local installation. Then,

You have two options:

1. Use [chromedriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) for Chrome 103 or
2. Install Chrome 109

I would recommend you to update your chrome broswer to version 109 unless its a fixed requirement. In that case, downgrade chromedriver version

Comment: Did you even read the question or the comments?   Your answer is not particularly helpful.